# Cython macro definition in structure

Tags: python, c, macros, structure, cython

I'm using Cython to import a structure to python from C while there are some macro definitions which include functions. I just don't how to realize the structure in Cython.

```
typedef struct _SparMat {
    int m, n;       

    int *rvec;      

    int *ridx;      
    double *rval;   

    int *cvec;      

    int *cidx;         
    double *cval;      

    int nnz;           
    int bufsz;         
    int incsz;         
    int flag;
#define MAT_ROWBASE_INDEX    (0x00000001)    
#define MAT_ROWBASE_VALUE    (0x00000002)
#define MAT_COLBASE_INDEX    (0x00000004)
#define MAT_COLBASE_VALUE    (0x00000008)
#define CSR_INDEX(flag)      ((flag) & MAT_ROWBASE_INDEX)
#define CSR_VALUE(flag)      ((flag) & MAT_ROWBASE_VALUE)
#define CSC_INDEX(flag)      ((flag) & MAT_COLBASE_INDEX)
#define CSC_VALUE(flag)      ((flag) & MAT_COLBASE_VALUE)
} SparMat, * matptr;
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Those macro definitions aren't actually part of the structure. Macro definitions can be put almost anywhere you want, so some people like to put them inside the structure or function or whatever they go with, but it doesn't matter; the whole `#define …` line turns into an empty string as far as the compiler is concerned. It's only where the macros are _used_ that the compiler sees anything.